# Moq repository setup of the FindBy method with Func<>

Tags: c#, tdd, repository, moq

Im new moq and have been struggling with the following.

I have mocked a list of List called _mockedThingsList

I would like to Moq the FindBy of my IRepository to return from this list of mocks based on the a linq query provided in my service that is being tested.

What I have currently have throws an exception and is as follows. What is wrong please?

```
mock.Setup(moq => moq.FindBy(It.IsAny<Func<IThing, bool>>()))
            .Returns((enumThingType tp) => _mockedThingsList.Where(x => x.ThingType == tp));
```

The repository interface looks like:

```
interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> FindAll();

    IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    void Add(T item);
    void Remove(T item);

    bool Contains(T item);
    int Count { get; }
}
```

And the service that would be tested with this mock

```
class ThingService
{
    private readonly IRepository<IThing> _repository;

    public ThingService(IRepository<IThing> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }


    public List<IThing> GetThings1()
    {
        return _repository.FindBy(y => y.ThingType == enumThingType.WhatEver).ToList();
    }

    public List<IThing> GetThings2()
    {
        return _repository.FindBy(y => y.Name == "What ever").ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're struggling because you are testing values and not contracts. If you want to test values, use a fake.

Comment: Sorry Im new to Moq and Im not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate please? mayeb give a quick example?

Comment: Can you provide the exception message/detail that you are getting?

Comment: @John - Tools like Moq are good for testing the interactions between classes on an individual class level. If you are trying to test multiple interactions, then you are testing 'integrations' and should look at using a fake, or test datasource.

Comment: @Pawan Mishra - An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Object of type 'System.Func`2[ThingNamespace.IThing,System.Boolean]' cannot be converted to type 'ThingNamespace.enumThingType'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be missing some context, but it appears to me that you are over-mocking. What's the purpose of mocking the list? You could easily return a concrete list and use that for your test.

Comment: I got the same vibe. My supposition is that he is over-mocking because he's trying to test at an integration level while still viewing his tests through the lens of a 'unit'.

Comment: I don't feel like this is TDD either.

Comment: Ok so based on yours and other feedback I have decided to go the fake route. I have created a concrete implementation of my repository which contains a List of mocks. This gives me my desired functionality. Is this approach more TDD or am I again taking it too far by using mocks in my List?

Comment: Like I said, I really don't know much about your system, if your finder is simply returning a list of domain objects, it's likely you're taking it too far by even using mocks in the list. I'd likely just new up a few objects in the list and return them.

Comment: Also, on the topic of TDD, again there's not much info here. You could be writing the test first, or after the production code. I can't tell from your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong in my interpretation but the signature of FindBy is returning an IEnumerable. Whereas while stubing, you are returning a delegate. I guess due to this mismatch in the return type, you are facing this issue. For testing purpose, why don't you just return some proper list from Returns method i.e.

```
(moq => moq.FindBy(It.IsAny<Func<IThing, bool>>()))
            .Returns(// return a proper List of type T);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: Object of type
>   'System.Func`2[ThingNamespace.IThing,System.Boolean]' cannot be
>   converted to type 'ThingNamespace.enumThingType'

Here is the thing. When you declare the stub on FindBy you are specifying the type parameter as : Func. Now in your Returns method the input parameter should exactly be of same type. Try the following code :

```
Func<IThing, bool> func => (IThing thing) => thing.ThingType == tp;

(moq => moq.FindBy(It.IsAny<Func<IThing, bool>>()))
            .Returns((func) => _mockedThingsList.Where(func));
```

Comment: .Returns(new[] { thingA, thingB };

Comment: you are part right. The following works but is not quite what I was after
'code' mockRep.Setup(moq => moq.FindBy(It.IsAny<Func<IThing, bool>>()))
                .Returns(new List<IThing>() { _mockedThingsList[0], _mockedThingsList[1] }); 

I was wanting to query the _mockedlist with the linq query in my service

Comment: My service contains the following code

public List<IThing> GetThings1() 
        {
            return _repository.FindBy(y => y.ThingType == enumThingType.WhatEver).ToList(); 
        } 

That would be the linq called against the moq repository and thererfore read from my _mockThingsList

Comment: I have updated my answer. I guess the problem you were facing was because of the way you defined the Returns method. Returns method should take input parameter to be of same type as defined in the Args<T>, while stubbing the method.

Comment: Not quite what I need. The Linq query executed should be the queries in the concreate ThingService. The linq statement will be differant Linq in differant situations. See for example GetThings1() and GetThings2() in the ThingService. The repository is passed into this concreate class and should return the items from the _mockedThingsList that its uses as its datastore. Sorry hope this clarifies things